# How to set Hidden TextField to Visible in iTextSharp 4.x

Tags: itext

I have an existing PDF with a couple of text fields set to Hidden in Acrobat. In specific circumstances we want to programatically un-hide the text fields prior to streaming the PDF to our eSignature provider.

I have tried various suggestions for making the fields visible using SetFieldProperties but am having no luck. There does not appear to be a "Visible" flag option and I do not know how to derive the TextField from the AcroFields.

```
var form = stamper.AcroFields;
form.SetFieldProperty("eSignature1_DateSigned", "setfflags", PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT, null);
```

I've tried setflags (one f) and that doesn't work either. Also, until we resolve some licensing issues we are unfortunately stuck with iTextSharp 4.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Just an FYI, although you say that you are stuck with 4 due to licensing issues I recommend you read Bruno Lowagie's post (the creator of iText) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12384410/231316

Comment: What kind of forms fields? AcroForm? XFA? Hybrid? If AcroForm, there are multiple flags allowing to hide text field widgets; cf. section 12.5.3 *Annotation Flags* in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Furthermore appearance streams might also might be missing or empty. You might want to post a sample PDF for inspection.

Comment: We are working on purchasing the 5.x license, know all about why that's a good thing, but it won't happen for several months.

Comment: I suppose this is an AcroForm but I am not at liberty to post a sample. The fields in question are set to HIDDEN in Acrobat and I want to set them to Visible. Seems like every post I've seen tells how to set to Hidden which is not my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is for Java. I'm guessing the values are the same. Pain in the butt to find this.  I don't know of any documentation.  I had to do it by trial and error. Amazing for something that we have to pay for...

```
form.setFieldProperty(fieldName, "clrflags", PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_HIDDEN, null);
```

If the PDF simply has the field set to hidden through Acrobat, then clear the hidden flag with `itext` instead of trying to set one of the visible flags.

Good luck.